# I cannot create more than 6 Jack Pulseaudio Sinks/Sources, is there a maximum? Only in Manjaro Linux, fine in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, pulse-audio

I have an audio setup (carried over from Windows) which involves numerous virtual audio sinks/sources, all routed through a DAW, for ducking and filtering, mostly for streams.

To do this on Linux, I've been using JACK2 and pulseaudio jack sinks/sources (module-jack-sink/module-jack-source).

I wrote a script to create the virtual devices. It calls pacmd or pactl (same results either way) to create multiple sinks and sources, and a few other things. The problem happens whether I do this with my script or directly in the CLI.

The command is "pactl load-module module-jack-sink sink_name=$name client_name=$name sink_properties=device.description=$dispname connect=false channels=2".

It worked fine on Ubuntu. Now, on Manjaro, The most sinks/sources I can create is 6. Occasionally it's 7, but I don't know why. It creates all sinks/sources perfectly up until that limit.

The output from pactl for sinks/sources over the limit is "Failure: Module initialization failed".

It's the same number whether I create all sinks, all sources, or a mix of both.

It happens whether I'm running jackd through qjackctl or directly, whether I connect jack to ALSA or dummy, whether I increase the port limit or not, whether I have more actual devices or not. I've tried many things.

I haven't found any config which might affect the maximum, or any documentation online to suggest that there is a maximum. I suspect there is some option for it somewhere which I can't find.

The only difference I can think of is that Jack 1 comes pre-installed with Manjaro. I uninstalled it and installed the latest Jack2 before doing anything else.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

one issue could be the limit being set for file descriptors for a process.
check
cat /proc//limits
there will be a line which shows the number of files that can be opened by a process.
if it exceeds this limit, assertions in code will fail and pulseaudio will crash.

```
Max open files            1024                 1024                 files
```

to increase this limit, you can use the command

```
prlimit -n4096 -p pid_of_pulseaudio
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `systemd` based Linux distro:

Run `sudo journalctl -f` and try to load the module. In my case this logs:

```
pulseaudio[194173]: The per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
pulseaudio[194173]: pa_thread_mq_init() failed.
pulseaudio[194173]: Failed to load module "module-jack-source": initialization failed.
```

The solution then is to increase the number of files that the pulseaudio service is allowed to open simultaneously.

This can be done on run-time with `prlimit` or `ulimit -n` however that's impractical, and requires `sudo` usage.

Pulseaudio is unusual for a service in that it runs as a user level service. Therefore you cannot add a `ulimit -n` or `prlimit` line to the startup command, because that command is not run as root. Pulseaudio's systemd file explicitly lists that it will not be run for the root user. Luckily systemd has a mechanism we can use.

Using `sudo` edit `/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service`.
In the section below the line `[Service]`, add a line that says `LimitNOFILE=1024`. Mind the odd capitalisation, that's required. Note that you can if necessary choose a higher number than 1024 files. But this was more than sufficient for my use case.
Then to reload this config and relaunch PulseAudio, run:

```sh
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

**Note: DO NOT attempt to use `sudo` for these commands. These are *user* level services**